# Laravel shows database row for test but not for other strings

Tags: php, laravel

I have actually no idea how I can fix this problem. I have tried quite a lot, so here is what I got:

I want to do a search function which checks different tables and different informations. Somehow I do only get results which I am directly related to (user_id in team table, the team I am in or my own username). My code looks like this:

```
public function search($param)
{
    $result = ['users' => [], 'teams' => []];

    $usersBySteamid = User::where('steamid', $param)->get();
    $usersByName = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$param.'%')->get();
    $teamsByName = Team::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$param.'%')->get();
    $users = $usersBySteamid->merge($usersByName);

    $result['users'] = $users;
    $result['teams'] = $teamsByName;

    return response()->json($result);
}
```

As a result I DO get my own username AND my own team, but not any other team or user.

Route:

```
Route::get('/admin/search/{param}', 'AdminController@search')->name('admin.search');
```

As a side information: I am using the auth middleware, but it did not make any problem until now, so I guess it might be irrelevant.

Comment: What is the value of $param that you are passing through?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: Try this: $usersBySteamid = User::where('steamid', $param); Log::info($usersBySteamid->toSql()); and check your laravel.log then. This will get you the query which could give you a hink.